# Create an object litteral containing properties from strings

Tags: javascript, json, eval, object-literal

How can I create an object evaluating the property names from variables?

For example:

I have the variable `myString = 'aString'`

And I want to create the object:

```
var obj = {
    aString : "value";
}
```

And I want to use the variable `myString` to create this.

The only solution I've come up with is something like this:

```
var string = '{"' + myString + '": value }';
var obj = $.parseJSON(string);
```

How can I make this more effective and cleaner?

Answer (score 6):

```
var str = "key";
var obj = {};
obj[str] = "value";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access/set object properties like this :

```
var obj = {};
obj[mystring] = 'value';
```